# an example of a field $k$ of characteristic $p$, and an irreducible, inseparable polynomial in $k[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

As stated, what would be an example to satisfy the above criterion?, what would be an example of a field $k$ of characteristic $p$, and an irreducible, inseparable polynomial in $k[x]$

Comment: The standard example is $k=K[T^p]$ for a field $K$ of characteristic $p$ and the polynomial $X^p-T^p$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  For $p $ prime,  let $K=\mathbb F_p (T) $, the field of rational polynomials in an indeterminate  $T $.  Then consider the polynomial  $q (x)=x^p-T\in K[x] $.

It's not separable because $q'(x)=0$ ( so it can't be relatively prime to it's derivative).  Or, we have for any root $\alpha$ that $q(x)=(x-\alpha)^p$ (freshman's binomial), so the root is repeated.

But it's irreducible. For that you can use Eisenstein.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific about an indeterminate $T$?

Comment: Deep question.  It's basically a variable, or an undefined entity outside the field $\mathbb F_p$.  Like an unknown.

Comment: So is $x^5-10$ would be an example for this if we just look at it in $\Field_5$?

Comment: No.  Rather $x^5-T$.  Remember we are working in $\mathbb F_5(T)[x]$.  $10\equiv0$ in $\mathbb F_5$, so  your example would just be $x^5$, which is not irreducible.